# type name errors and others in IOS project

Tags: ios

I am trying to link iOS-ngn-stak project to my app following their instructions which written here:
http://code.google.com/p/idoubs/wiki/Building_iDoubs_v2_x
but having these new errors, any help please 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like it doesnt see the code as C++ but as C/objC only.

rename m files that use headers from the project to mm to make them objC++

e.g. your ViewController.m to ViewController.mm